# Comments form won't appear

Tags: comments

I'm switching a website from Disqus back to the regular Comment module. After installing the module, I can configure it just fine as an administrator and add comments on some dummy articles. But when I test it out as an anonymous user or sign in as an authenticated user, I'm unable to write comments. I can see the comments, but the form to write comments just isn't there.

I ensured that all users have permission to post comments. I've refreshed the cache numerous times, ran update.php and composer update. I've restarted the server as well as the PC.

Comment: As the admin, you can see the post comment form, but as an auth user with permission, you cannot?

Comment: That's correct.